# Displaying ArrayList<String> in JTextArea

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

So when a button is clicked my method returns an arraylist of strings, I'm trying to display the strings line by line in a JtextArea. This is my first time playing around with GUIs in eclipse, but so far I'm at

```
JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Coordinate Anomalies");
btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        ArrayList<String> anomalies = vessels.coordinateAnomaly(); 
    }
});
btnNewButton_1.setBounds(10, 45, 172, 23);
frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);

JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setBounds(10, 79, 172, 339);
frame.getContentPane().add(textArea);
```

I was thinking that I could potentially do

```
JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Coordinate Anomalies");
btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        ArrayList<String> anomalies = vessels.coordinateAnomaly(); 
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setText(anomalies);
        textArea.setBounds(10, 79, 172, 339);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textArea);
    }
});
```

This definitely does not work, and if it did would display strings in ArrayList formatting, So I should have a loop some wheres, but I'm a little lost. 

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Based on format you might want to use append instead of settext... and if you want to print just array list you need to (with formatting) do Arrays.toString(anomallies) otherwise do a for loop. for(String s: anomalies) textArea.append(s)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one:

```
for(String a : anomalies){
   textArea.append(a + "\n");
}
```

instead of:

```
textArea.setText(anomalies);
```

Comment: This totally works, but the list that appears is invisible until I highlight it and the list is larger than the frame, is there a scroll-able option ?

Comment: @guy_sensei you can create JTextArea inside [JScrollPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: @guy_sensei frame.getContentPane().add(jp); - you should add scroll pane, not textArea

Comment: @guy_sensei and what you exactly mean by invisible??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77747/discussion-between-m-cekiera-and-guy-sensei).

Comment: unfortunately I'm on a regulated internet connection that says chat url is blocked :(

Comment: @guy_sensei delate frame.getContentPane().add(textArea); it is enough if you add JScrollPane, also meaby you should add your btnNewButton to other part of frames BorderLayout, NORTH or SOUTH for example

Comment: last try :P mayby you will find something useful it this simplified [example](http://hastebin.com/basadameki.avrasm)

Answer (score 0):

when adding JTextArea to JFrame just add scroll pane in it like this

add(new JScrollPane(textarea));

Answer (score 0):

Ended up following m.cekiera advice

```
  for(String a : anomalies){
                        if(a.equals(anomalies.get(anomalies.size()-1))){
                            textArea_1.append(a);
                        }else{
                           textArea_1.append(a + "\n");
                        }
                    }
```